# Ansible import_task and use serial syntax for execution task host one by one

Tags: ansible, task

I have a role task and I want ansible execute all task for each server one by one. I found throttle instruction, but it comptatible for 2.9.0 ansible version and I have 2.8.6 ansible version.
For instance, execute name1, name2 for host1 and after execute name1, name2 for host2...

main.yml

```
- name: Configure
  import_tasks: "task_role.yml"
  tags:
    - task_role
```

task_role.yml

```
---
- name: name1
  ---

- name: name2
  ---
```

inventory file

```
[serveur]
host1
host2
host3
```

the problem is the syntax, I cannot add task instruction on task_role.yml, so how I use the serial instruction without task instruction.

Comment: You can try follow this link:
https://serverfault.com/questions/736452/ansible-how-to-run-one-task-host-by-host

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **serial** module to make it run in one server at a time

```
- name: test play
  hosts: webservers
  serial: 3
  gather_facts: False

  tasks:
    - name: first task
      command: hostname
    - name: second task
      command: hostname
```

In this example you can see that the number is set to 3, so it will run the playbook in 3 servers at a time.
The output will look like this:

```
PLAY [webservers] ****************************************

TASK [first task] ****************************************
changed: [web3]
changed: [web2]
changed: [web1]

TASK [second task] ***************************************
changed: [web1]
changed: [web2]
changed: [web3]

PLAY [webservers] ****************************************

TASK [first task] ****************************************
changed: [web4]
changed: [web5]
changed: [web6]

TASK [second task] ***************************************
changed: [web4]
changed: [web5]
changed: [web2]

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************
web1      : ok=2    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0
web2      : ok=2    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0
web3      : ok=2    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0
web4      : ok=2    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0
web5      : ok=2    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0
web6      : ok=2    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

In your case I understand that you would want to set it to "1" so it will run in one server at a time.
For more information you can also check [this link](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_strategies.html#setting-the-batch-size-with-serial) which will redirect you to the official Ansible page where I took the information from.

Comment: thanks for replying, I edit the question, the problem it is a role task and I cannot add task instruction on yml.

Comment: Unfortunately this kind of modifications can only be done at strategy level, it is not possible to assign a different strategy per role.
You should consider splitting the tasks that require different strategies in different playbooks in order to get the behavior you expect.